# Process or program running on specific machines using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, scripting

i'm new in the world of programming and on powershell scripting. My collegue gave me this command to run to identify if YES or NO the program `PROGRAM.EXE` is running on a list of computers. But i found it hard to do it on over 50 machines. I want to run it using powershell the forEach function.
This is what i've done already but i don't have the expected result.
Usually he uses this
`> tasklist /s COMPUTER1 /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq PROGRAM.EXE")`
This gave several result and when the program is installed, it return the name, and the PID of the program , else it says `aucune tƒche en service ne correspond aux critŠres sp‚cifi‚s.`
I want to use it but with powershell, with the list of computers.

This is what i've tried but i feelled bloked

```
$postes = @('COMPUTER1', 'COMPUTER2', 'COMPUTER3')

Foreach($element in $postes) 
{ 
    $( tasklist /s $($element) /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq PROGRAM.EXE")
}
```

I expect to switch case the result if or no the program is installed. But the result is not controlable that way. Can someone help please.

Thank you all.

Comment: In PS you don't need a loop to run commands on multiple remote computers. You can use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3). And I'd recommend to use native PowerShell cmdlets instead of CMD tools. For example [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7.3). You may read more about PowerShell remoting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/08-powershell-remoting?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thank you @Olaf. I'm reading it, when i'll update my code. I will share it with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the amount of remote computers you want to query you could check if you can reach each individual computer in a loop and only query the online ones  ... something like this:

```
$computerList = Get-Content -Path 'c:\files\mycomputer.txt'
$NomProgramme = 'XWin_MobaX'

$data = 
foreach ($computer in $computerList) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -HideComputerName -ScriptBlock {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Computer       = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME 
                Online         = $True
                ProgramRunning = if (Get-Process -Name $USING:NomProgramme -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { $True } else { $false }  
            }
        } |
            Select-Object -ExcludeProperty RunspaceId
    }
    else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Computer       = $computer 
            Online         = $false
            ProgramRunning = 'n/a'  
        }
    }
} 
$data | Format-Table -AutoSize
$data | Export-Csv -Path c:\files\Services.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you have really a lot of computers to check you may switch to PowerShell version 7 and use its builtin ability to run commands in parallel with `Foreach-Object -Parallel` You can read more about here: [Get-Help Foreach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thanks you Olaf, maybe we should add the `-ComputerName` parameter on this line to really test on the remote computer.  `Get-Process -Name $programRunning -ComputerName $computer`  this partilly solves the problem but still crashing when it can't open the distant connection.

Comment: Oooops, I actually forgot the remote execution part ... corrected it now ... try!

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions to access these computers remotely, and WMI is enabled on those computers, you can use the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet.

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path computers.txt # Text file with one computer on each line
foreach($computer in $computers){
    $processes = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Query "SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'PROGRAM.EXE'"
    $programRunning = $processes.Count -gt 0
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Computer = $computer; ProgramRunning = $programRunning }
}
```

Or if you prefer it in a one-liner:

```
cat computers.txt|%{[pscustomobject]@{Computer=$_;Running=[bool](gwmi -cn $_ -q "Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='PROGRAM.EXE'")}}
```

If you need to run it quickly, I would suggest running it in parallel using the [`PSParallel`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSParallel/2.2.2) module from the PowerShell Gallery.

This would let you use the `Invoke-Parallel` cmdlet in the one-liner:

```
Install-Module PSParallel -Scope CurrentUser
cat computers.txt|Invoke-Parallel{[pscustomobject]@{Computer=$_;Running=[bool](gwmi -cn $_ -q "Select * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='PROGRAM.EXE'")}}
```

Comment: You should not use `Get-WmiObject` anymore. Instead use the more modern `Get-CimInstance`! ;-)

Comment: Hi DotNetPadawan, thank fo your answer. I agree with @Olaf that you shouldn't use the Get-WmiObject, it's deprecated.